# Python selenium - Unable to capture and send_keys to the input box

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to automate login to the website https://plus.credit-suisse.com. The code below takes us to the last step where the password is supposed to be entered.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://plus.credit-suisse.com")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Sign-in"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Enter Credit Suisse ID (usually your registered email address)"]'))).send_keys("username")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="mod_cookie_policy_btn_close"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Enter Password to sign-in"]'))).click()

time.sleep(5)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password')))
element.send_keys('password')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Login"]'))).click()
```

Now the line

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password')))
```

throws the **TimeoutException**. And this is the last step.

Comment: did you test it without `"--headless"` to see what is really displaying?

Comment: I found 3 elements with ID `password` - and this can make problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this page has 3 elements with ID `password`.

Last element is the correct one but `element_to_be_clickable` may gives first one.

You may have to use XPath to get correct one

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="csplusSecondView"]//input[@id="password"]')))
```

Comment: Tested, this should work